# Is it faster to obtain current user data by using a filter or related object reference?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Which of the two methods are quicker in obtaining current user specific data? For example:

```
class FriendProfileDetail(ListView):
    model = Friend
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(friend_of=self.request.user.profile)
```

VS

```
class FriendProfileDetail(ListView):
    model = Friend
    def get_queryset(self): 
        queryset = self.request.user.profile.friends.all()
    return queryset
```

Comment: There is absolutely no difference. These both do exactly the same query.

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd say that second it's faster. You can prove it with django debug toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between this two filters and queries. But, in my opinion, as [**The Zen of Python**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3) says: *"Explicit is better than implicit."*.

So as your `ListView` is corresponding to the `Friend` model, it is more straightforward to use `self.model` instead of `self.request.user` for object filtering.

The other thing is that the `self.request.user` filtering is shorter and does not use `filter()` but `all()`, which seems simple.

No matter what, the result will be the same. Just choose one way and do it.